# How do I increment by columns instead of rows?

Tags: excel

```
=IF(AND($C$1="Jan",$C$2="Parc Sovereign"),INDIRECT("'1'!AH" &A20),IF(AND($C$1="Feb",$C$2="Parc Sovereign"),'1'!AH363))
```

Ok I have placed my formula here, my problem is that I only know how to increment the first INDIRECT function by row as based from the number I enter from A20. 
So if let's say I enter 19 at `A20`, my `INDIRECT` function result will be `'1'!AH19`, but I am doing it the wrong way, I would like to edit the column instead of the row everytime I change the value in `A20`.

and I have plenty of `A20's` to be taking data from so I can't be editing them everytime I need to change the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the second optional parameter of the INDIRECT function to FALSE, then use R1C1-style references.

Alternatively you can use the ADDRESS function:

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(rownumber, columnnumber))
```